# How to properly add an object to a list when the list is a custom class object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get a null reference exception when I try to add a region to the list and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I simply can't figure it and I've done this a million times.

```
public List<Region> regions;

public class Region
{
    public int x_size;
    public int y_size;

    public enum terrain
    {
        desert,
        lowlands,
        crater,
        city
    };

    public terrain ground;
}

private void NewRegion()
{
    Region thisRegion = new Region();
    thisRegion.x_size = Random.Range(25, 50);
    thisRegion.y_size = Random.Range(25, 50);
    thisRegion.ground = Region.terrain.desert;
    regions.Add(thisRegion);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regions` list is null, you can't add anything to it. In `Start()` do:

```
regions = new List<Region> ();
```

Answer (score 2):

You just did not instanciate your list of `Region` (regions), so it is null. Look at the `new List<Region>()` part :

```
public List<Region> regions = new List<Region>();

public class Region
{
    public int x_size;
    public int y_size;

    public enum terrain
    {
        desert,
        lowlands,
        crater,
        city
    };

    public terrain ground;
}

private void NewRegion()
{
    Region thisRegion = new Region();
    thisRegion.x_size = Random.Range(25, 50);
    thisRegion.y_size = Random.Range(25, 50);
    thisRegion.ground = Region.terrain.desert;
    regions.Add(thisRegion);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `Region` a [`[Serilizable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization) type:

```
[Serializable]
public class Region
{
    public int x_size;
    public int y_size;

    public enum terrain
    {
        desert,
        lowlands,
        crater,
        city
    };

    public terrain ground;
}
```

Since the field `regions` is `public` it would be automatically serilaized and initialized by the Unity Inspector anyway **if the `Region` was serializable**.

So now the upper code would have two advantages

- You don't have to have the code

  ```
  region = new List<Region>();
  ```

  nowhere. It would be initaialized automatically by Unity.

  It is still recommneded to have it, though, but I wouldn't do it in `Start` but simply like

  ```
  public List<Region> regions = new List<Region>();
  ```
- The other really huge advantage is that now you should actually see that list in the Unity Inspector so you can directly from the Editor add and adjust elements without having to hardcode them via a script.